# How do I remove this space in this sed regex?

Tags: regex, git, bash, sed, ps1

I have a script from a coworker that formats my prompt.  It grabs my branch and formats with the code below using sed (note I hardcoded the branch name for testing):

```
echo "* master" | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ \1 /'
```

In an effort to learn more of what the script was doing, I was playing around with it.  I noticed it prints the name of my branch "master" but it leaves the space before the branch name (" master").  I want to eliminate the space.  I can't seem to do this though.

Comment: Unrelated to the regex issue, the way to find out the current branch (if any) is to use git's `symbolic-ref` sub-command on `HEAD`.  For instance, `git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD` prints the name of the current branch, or nothing at all if not on a branch (with an error message if not in a git tree at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the space before your `\1`. Probably you want to remove the space behind it as well.

```
echo "* master" | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks!  I couldn't figure out whether to use a '/s' or if it was just a space.  I was really confused!

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the problem by not using sed

```
echo "* master" | cut -c3-
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  That works!  However, what is "cut" doing?  I can't find documentation on it.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you are looking for this:

```
kent$  echo "* master" | sed 's/ \+//'                          
*master
```

this sed line removes the **first** occurrence of one or more spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  However, when I run this I still get the full expression with the space.

Answer (score 0):

the original sed is a bit strange compare to your hard coding branch

1. It delete the line if it not start with a "*" and try to load a new one. Your branch is coming from a file or command with multi line ?
2. It take end of line after "* ". It is simplier to just "remove" begin of line

   Your_source | sed -n '/[^*]/ {s/^* //p;q;}'

take only line starting with `"* "`, remove begin, print it and quit (no more than 1 line starting with `"* "` treated)